# in R find duplicates by column 1 and filter by not NA column 3

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
c <- c(1,NA,2,4,NA,1,2,2)
df <-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I have a dataframe with some duplicate variables in column 1 but when I use the duplicated function, it randomly chooses the row after de-duping using duplicate(function)

```
dedup_df = df[!duplicated(df$a), ]
```

How can I ensure that the output returns me the row that does not contain an NA on column c ?

I tried to use the dplyr package but the output prints only a result

```
library(dplyr)
options(dplyr.print_max = Inf )
df %>%                    ## source dataframe
group_by(a) %>%         ## grouped by variable
filter(!is.na(c) )  %>% ## filter by Gross value
as.data.frame(dedup_df)
```

Comment: It is not clear what your expected output is.  The `dedup_df` does not have any NA rows from c

Comment: @akrun, yes dedup_df does not contain NA when you run it once but it is not assured that is the case. So what I want to achieve in all runs that no row that is duplicated would be chosen with an NA in that column

Comment: In that case just do `df %>% filter(!is.na(c)) %>% .[!duplicated(.$a),]` or a double `filter` i.e. `df %>% filter(!is.na(c)) %>% filter(!duplicated(a))`

Comment: @akrun for dplyr it only gives me a subset of the output ? i was puzzled why it does not give me full ouput.. i was working off 100000 n expected output is only 200 less but it only gives me 4958 no matter what.. is there a limit that i am hitting?

Comment: I am not sure what might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `duplicated` function to remove duplicate observations (lines) using a column as key from a data frame is correct.

But it seems that you are worried that it may keep a line that contains NA in another column and drop another line that contains a non NA value.

I'll use you example, but with a slight modification

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
c <- c(NA,1,2,4,NA,1,2,2)
df <-data.frame(a,b,c)

> df
  a b  c
1 A 1 NA
2 A 1  1
3 A 2  2
4 B 4  4
5 B 1 NA
6 B 1  1
7 C 2  2
8 C 2  2
```

In this case, your dedup_df contains an NA for the first value.

```
> dedup_df = df[!duplicated(df$a), ]
> dedup_df
  a b  c
1 A 1 NA
4 B 4  4
7 C 2  2
```

Solution:

Reorder df by column c first and then use the same command. This reordering by column c will send all NAs to the end of the data frame.  When the `duplicated` passes it will see these lines having NA last and will tag them as TRUE if there was a previous one without NA.

```
df = df[order(df$c),]
dedup_df = df[!duplicated(df$a), ]

> dedup_df
  a b c
2 A 1 1
6 B 1 1
7 C 2 2
```

You can also reorder in descending order

```
df = df[order(df$c,decreasing = T),]
dedup_df = df[!duplicated(df$a), ]

> dedup_df
  a b c
4 B 4 4
3 A 2 2
7 C 2 2
```